# load revelant data when clicking on link using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, sql

Hey, I'm trying to make an Address book for my site and I was thinking of having two panes. The one on the left to have Contact names, and the one on the right to have the contact details.

I can get the Contact pane loaded up using a while loop to cycle through my query, but then I was thinking that I really had no Idea how to load the details of that contact when the user clicks on a specific contact name.

How would I be able to approach this problem?

Comment: What relationship is there in the html between the two panes?

Comment: well pane 1 say has John Doe, you click on John Doe then in pane 2 you get his info like Address, Numbers, Comments, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like:

```
<div id="contactNamesPane">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="names" id="johnDoe">Doe, John</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="contactDetailsPane">
</div>

$('contactNamesPane a.names').click(
   var thisContactId = $(this).attr('id');
   $('contactDetailsPane')
        .load('http://path/to/script.php?contactId=' + thisContactId + ' #' + thisContactId);
);
```

This has the assumptions that you have a php script to generate the contact details (located at `http://path/to/script.php` and this script can take a `GET` variable in order to show the particular individual.

It also assumes that this data will be placed inside an element of an id equal to the contact's name.

A vaguely coherent demo's posted on my server at: http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/so/loadDemo.html

Comment: hmmm, forgive me for sounding a little out of the loop here but I'm having a brain fart and I can't seem to form a complete thought bubble here. In my addresbook.ajax.php I have queries with in a SWITCH statement to perform actions based on usage. What would I need to do for it to return the data that the Details Pane will be populated with?

Comment: ah, ya i see. Can you post the PHP portion of your example please

Comment: @s2xi, I'd suggest asking separate questions to resolve those issues. In writing the above, I rather assumed you'd got the php part sorted out. I can't post *my* php, because the data's being loaded from a static html file, just for demo purposes.

Comment: ya, i saw that ;-) I was able to get the logic behind the javascript thanks to you. I guess now I just need to figure out how to output from a sql query.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the list on the left add the id of the contact to the rel

```
<ul id="contacts">
    <li><a href="#" rel="ID_OF_CONTACT">Name Here</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Then with jquery you can use the rel attribute and peform a ajax request to a php page that returns the info of the contact with that id

```
$("#contact a").click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("rel");
    $.get("url_of_php_page", { id: id },
        function(data){
            // do something with the data
        }
    );

});
```

---

use [jquery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) instead